# Как на Bitbucket создать pipelines, которые будут создавать базу данных Postrgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Имеет скрипт с созданием schema для базы данных Postgresql. Как будет выглядить yml  файл для такого Pipeline, который должен будет создать базу данных postgresql и запустить скрипт schema.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for Java (Maven).
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/zd-5Mw for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: maven:3.3.9

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - maven
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn -B verify # -B batch mode makes Maven less verbose

image: node:6.9.4
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
        services:
          - postgres

definitions:
  services:
    postgres:
      image: postgres
            variables:
              POSTGRES_DB: 'test'
              POSTGRES_USER: 'test'
              POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'test'
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете образ postgres с docker hub-а, то его можно расширить скриптами для создания БД. Подробнее читайте в разделе **How to extend this image** на [странице образа](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). Если вкратце, то можно добавить своих скриптов, которые будут вызываться при первой инициализации БД. Надо понимать, что расширив его, Вы его должны будете положит в registry до которого bitbucket сможет дотянуться.